# Java Card Conversion

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I have written a Java Card App and want to upload it to a Card. But the card supports Java 2.1.1 standard. So I am looking for a way of generating a 2.1.1 Compliant CAP file with my 2.2.2 Kit

I have:

- Java 1.6
- GPShell 1.4.2
- Java Card 2.2.2
- JCOP 30 V2 Card

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you don't use any new features only offered in Java Card 2.2 you still have  a twofold problem: it concerns the format as well as the content of your CAP file.

1. your CAP file is in Java Card 2.2 format, which is sligtly different to Java Card 2.1
2. your CAP file contents fit to a Java Card 2.2.2 API, which has some extensions compared to Java Card 2.1

Therefore your Java Card 2.2 kit doesn't help you.

You need to convert (class-->cap) your classes...

1. using a Java Card 2.1 converter (in order to get your CAP files in Java Card 2.1 format)
2. using EXP (expport) files fitting to the Java Card 2.1.1 API beeing present on your card.

The appropriate EXP files are needed, because the CAP file doesn't contain any symbolic information. 
Its replaced in the converter by numeric values (tags) that must correspond to the structure of the API on your card. 
The EXP files contain the name to tag mapping.

You can still get the old (2.1.1) development kit (730 KBytes) here:

http://java.sun.com/javacard/downloads/index.jsp#devkit

Good luck.